# I lost my videos, how will I retrieve them?

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer, media-files

I have a problem on retrieving my files from my phone to my PC. I have 'moved' my DCIM folder from my phone to my PC. Will i be able to retrieve them? help please...

Comment: my videos are gone

Comment: Can't you just move (or copy) them back? Where have they gone? What exactly is the problem? You'll need to provide more details if you're to get any useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you moved them onto your computer you can just copy the DCIM folder back onto the sdcard or internal storage of your device.

If this isn't the case there are several tools to recover lost data on your harddrive here is a good one: https://www.piriform.com/recuva